# finding the common rows between 2 files using awk

Tags: awk

I have 2 text files called one and two like these 2 examples:

one:

```
chr5    315038  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315039  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
chr5    315010  315111  AHRR
chr5    315032  315133  AHRR
```

two:

```
chr5    315035  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
chr12   49314934    49315035    CCDC65
```

I want to get similar rows of these 2 files based on 4 columns. for example for the files one and two, the expected output would look like the following since this line is exactly the same in 2 files (for all columns).

expected output:

```
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using the following command but the results is not what i want. do you know how to fix it?

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2$3$3]++;next}!a[$4$3$2$1]' one.txt two.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: What about using good old: `comm -12 <(sort one.txt) <(sort two.txt)`

Comment: You can't stick a bunch of fields together and hope to get a unique value. `a bc` -> `abc` and `ab c` -> `abc`. Put commas between so SUBSEP is used. Also, I can't imagine why you thought `$1$2$3$3` from one.txt would ever occur as `$4$3$2$1` in two.txt. Take a second to **think** about your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check complete line itself then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a'  one  two
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [ravindersingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) you can opt for `awk` to solve your problem:

The following `awk` script does the same:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} a[$0]' one two
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```

This approach does not require to sort the files however it consumes more memory because you store the lines in an associative array. More memory consumption but faster result on big files (as they do not need to be sorted).

If you want a more direct approach you can use either `comm` :

```
$ comm -1 -2 <(sort one) <(sort two)
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```

> a tool that compares two sorted files line by line

or `grep` using option `-f` (the first file will define a list of pattern that grep will use to query the second file)

```
$ grep -f one two
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```

> `-f FILE, --file=FILE`
>   Obtain patterns from `FILE`, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the `-e (--regexp)` option,
>   search for all  patterns  given.   The  empty  file  contains  zero 
>   patterns,  and
>                 therefore matches nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Perl Solution

```
$ cat user10657934_one.txt
chr5    315038  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315039  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
chr5    315010  315111  AHRR
chr5    315032  315133  AHRR

$ cat user10657934_two.txt
chr5    315035  315059  PDCD6
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
chr12   49314934    49315035    CCDC65

$ perl -lne ' push @{$kv{$_}} ,$ARGV ; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_" if scalar(@{$kv{$_}}>1) } } ' user10657934_one.txt user10657934_two.txt
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```

or

```
$ perl -lne ' $kv{$_}.="$ARGV;" ; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_" if $kv{$_}=~/;.*;/ } } ' user10657934_one.txt user10657934_two.txt
chr5    315035  315136  AHRR
```